# How to insert a fragment of web page into Excel parsed to column/rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, html, import, parser

I'm selecting a fragment of a page, like part of a right column with suggestion links on a youtube page. I want it with pictures come to sheet in sorted order. But Excel says, that

> "The data you're pasting isn't the same size as your selection. Do you
>   want to paste anyway?".

**How to find out which size Excel mean? 
Or how to option autosize paste?**

While web page import couldn't guess div structure of such a page from top,
the Excel comprehend the contents of the selected divs. It comes well parsed, even picture pasted, yet not fit to right cells.

Comment: Don't paste into a selected range. Just click a cell and paste.  The cell you selected will be the upper left cell of the area you pasted.

Comment: yes, it pastes, but looks ugly. 
sorry, it doesh't look like parsed contents of each div from html to separated cell. 
i'm noob in excel, may be i've missed something?

Comment: say, i've selected 3 cells at random page https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g024lzsknDo. 
it looks like every cell in the page should fit into 5 cells in sheet, in a row or in a column.
yet it doesn't.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "cells" on a youtube webpage. Are you expecting Excel to show the result as if it were displaying HTML? It won't.

Comment: the contents of the column on the web page looks like cells in a one-column table (actually presented by styled divs inside).
may be area would be more suitable term, by i try to refer to the structure of the info.

Comment: i just expect to see each div content (from inside of the common div of the visible cell at the page) to be parsed as a content of a cell of my sheet.

Comment: I tried copying and pasting 3 pictures from the YouTube page you linked. I got the three pictures on top of three hyperlinks to the pages the pics refer to.

Comment: Thanks, it pastes. With several trial-and-error i figured out every web page entry fits 4 cells vertically(not 5). If to select 12 sheet cells for 3 page entries, it fits without warning. Yet picture doesn't fit cell's size(, which looks ugly(((

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.